# Запрос к сайту https с сертификатом через urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, urllib

Здравствуйте.
Как правильно получит содержимое сайта, который использует https-соединение?
Если обычный запрос выглядит так:

```
html=urlopen("https://site.ru")
```

тогда как должен выглядеть запрос к https://site.ru?
Я пробовал скачивать сертификат сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Положил этот файл в папку с программой.
И пробую получить html таким образом, указывая именованный аргумент cafile:

```
html=urlopen("https://krober.biz"+pageUrl, cafile='site.cer')
```

И всё равно такое же исключение:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)>
```

Прошу подсказать, может это сделать как-то по другому? Необходимо получить source страницы.
Спасибо.

Comment: если вы в браузере зайдёте с той же системы, то ругается на сертификат этого сайта?

Comment: jfs, нет, не ругается

Comment: на OSX на Python 3.6 похожая проблема решалась [установкой обновлённых сертификатов](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10779#issuecomment-309134512). У вас похоже Windows на неизвестной версии Питона. `ssl.create_default_context()` и так должен был системные сертификаты подгрузить. Можно попробовать обновить систему, Питон¶ Чтобы не приходилось во всех скриптах `certifi` прописывать (которая от Mozilla сертификаты берёт), попробуйте `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` переменную окружения значению возвращаемому командой `python -m certifi` присвоить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если задача стоит в том, чтобы игнорировать ошибку:

```
import ssl
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://site.ru')

context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
with urlopen(req, context=context) as response:
    print(response.read())
```

Но лучше установить пакет свежих корневых сертификатов

```
pip install certifi
```

и использовать их для валидации

```
import certifi
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://site.ru')

with urlopen(req, cafile=certifi.where()) as response:
    print(response.read())
```

Comment: Спасибо. Слышал про certifi, не знал как его применить в urllib.